# Group On whole report in MS Access Reports 2007

Tags: ms-access, report

Need to make a group header and group footer which should be grouped on whole report.
What Expression should I use in the Group & Sort Expression?

Comment: By "group header/footer...on whole report" do you mean the report header/footer? In short, if you're doing summarizing on all the records in the whole report, you don't need a group at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand what you mean by "*group header and group footer which should be grouped on whole report*".

Perhaps you could include a dummy field in your report's data source with a query:

```
SELECT
    1 AS dummy_field,
    existing_field1,
    existing_field2,
    existing_field3
FROM
    YourTable;
```

Then group on dummy_field ... you would get a single group since dummy_field has the same value in every row.

Does that accomplish what you want?